# chrono literals in VS2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, user-defined-literals

The following code gives me a compile time error:

```
#include <chrono>

int main() {
    auto day = 24h;
    return 0;
}
```

Error C3688: invalid literal suffix 'h'; literal operator or literal operator template 'operator ""h' not found.

I'm trying this on Visual Studio 2015 Update 1, which according to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt243853.aspx) should work, so what's going on?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The literals aren't in the global namespace. Add this:

```
using namespace std::chrono_literals;
```

Depending on the situation, you might also consider using:

```
using std::chrono::operator""h;
```

instead of importing every name from that namespace if you need more fine grained control.